# C#'s LINQ for collection manipulation equivalent in ruby

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linq, collections

I'm quite new to ruby development, and i'm currently working on a project in ruby 1.8.7 using rails 2.3.11, and I was wondering if there is an equivalent in this language to C#'s linq for the collection manipulation, such as a where clause.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent of `where` of Linq in Ruby is [find_all](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001487)

Check the [documentation for the Enumerable Module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) for other functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do similar stuff as in linq, anyhow the syntax is rather different.
You would write something like this:

```
a.select { |i|
    (do something with item i and decide whether 
     it should be added to the output array 
     or not by returning true or false)
}
```

Assuming a is an array, this code would return a new array containing the elements that passed your validation code.

[Documentation of the array class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000251)

Answer (score 0):

named scopes may be what you are looking for...I think rails 3.1 has some more in depth "where" like stuff, as well.